# Download Image from URL and Create a new Folder in wp-contents and save them there

Tags: block-editor

I am using Lazy Blocks Plugin to create a custom block with my design. However I want to download the images and then save them into a new folder and then get the URL.

```
<?php
$saveImg_Name = str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($prod_name));
@$rawImage_URL = file_get_contents($prod_img);
if($rawImage_URL){
 file_put_contents("/wp-content/product-images/".$saveImg_Name.".jpg", $rawImage_URL);
 echo "Successfull";
}
else{
  echo "Not Successfull";
}
?>

<img loading="lazy" width="300" height="300" src="<?php echo("/wp-content/product-images/".$saveImg_Name.".jpg"); ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_name ?>">
```

This is the kind of code I am writing by watching a video from YouTube. It never saves the image nor creates a folder in wp-content. I want it solved! Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `@` suppresses error messages - there could well be a `file_get_contents()` error relevant to your troubleshooting efforts which you are not seeing. That said, we could use some more information - have you verified that this code is indeed running? Does it print the `"Successfull"` message? Does it display any errors when it runs? Have you verified the contents of `$prod_img` - what are they? The question indicates `$prod_img` might be a URL - but you're also using it nearly verbatim as a filename, and URLs contain characters which are not valid in UNIX filenames.

Comment: I've verified everything. The ```Successfull``` message prints and the ```$prod_img``` is also a URL. However, there's no error message when the code runs.